# Get JSON data with jQuery on Opera gives error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, opera

I'm very new at jQuery. Developing a project (with no server, just click on html file) and I need to read a **local** JSON file which named "data.json".

When I writed,

```
$.getJSON('./data.json');
```

Opera gives me a error,

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/****/****/****/data.json' from origin 'null'has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

I need a solution for this, can't reach for 3 days.

Comment: The error is telling you the issue.  Ajax doesn't like the `file:///` protocol.  You will need to start up a local server instance to access `localhost` files.

Comment: Suggestion of an easy to use local server solution: [Uniform Server](https://www.uniformserver.com/)

Comment: Quite a few light weight http server packages available on npm as well.